# Capistrano Global Roles File?

Tags: capistrano

forgive me i'm new to capistrano

we have multiple sites we want to deploy with capistrano. Each site is deployed to the same set of servers. Instead of adding the same set of servers to each capfile for each site how would we have 1 file to holds roles and tell each site capfile to use the global roles file?

Comment: found it, you use [code](load "<FILENAME>")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Multistage extension
https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Multistage-Extension